# Pandas populate dataframe from a loop

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I need to create an empty data frame to create the columns and populated within a loop with a SQL query result.

My query looks:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('connection')
script = 'select * from table  WHERE id=1111;'

query = text(script)
result = engine.execute(query)

rep = {"\\": "", "{": "","}":"",'"':"","attributes:":""}


def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text    


df = pd.DataFrame()


for i in result:
    clean = replace_all(i[3],rep)
    field = clean.split(',')
    for item in field:
        info = item.split(":")
        df[info[0]] = info[1]

print(df)
```

When I print I see the columns created but any data inside why?

> Empty DataFrame Columns: [customer_id, from_country,......] Index: []
>
> [0 rows x 63 columns]

Comment: Do you want content of data in dataframe? then, may be you can try `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` after `for` loop and before `print(df)`

Comment: I have just to fix the script without this confuse dictionary data that I created. I suppose to add a new column with a value in the line df[info[0]] = info[1] @0p3n5ourcE

Comment: In your for loop, you can remove other statements and try `df = df.append(dict([item.split(":")]), ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending the new data to the dataframe at any stage.

You can append a line to it by building a dictionary

```
d = {info[0]:info[1]}
df = df.append(d, ignore_index=True)
```

where info[0] would be your column name and info[1] would be the value.

Comment: how to do it? is the question mr